# Bootstrap column width are different with different content

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, multiple-columns, grid-layout

**I try to style the inner content part of my wordpress site with Bootstrap. I'm using the same grid layout on each site. The content changes on every site and this change the Bootstrap column width, depending on the content I guess.**

Here is an example of a site, where column width is almost perfect:
http://madtrash.com/item/040001452/

Here is an example of a site, where the column width is too small at some places:
http://madtrash.com/item/020000180/

On the following page is an example, where the column width expands too much:
/item/010320105/

**It seems that the column width changes, depending on the textual or image content?**

**What can I do to have the same column width on every page?** I tried so many thing, but wasn't successful, yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of unnecessary `.row` classes in your templates. Additionally, there's a CSS declaration for `.row .row{ width: auto; }` which is changing how `.row` normally behaves in the bootstrap grid.

So, remove the `.row` classes from every element that's a parent to a `.container` and you should be good to go. You can also delete that CSS declaration.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! The problem is that I don't have access to the parent rows, because they belong to the Wordpress theme. I can only edit the code in the .container row. I'll assume the only thing I can do is to change the Wordpress template? Or is there any other possibility?

Comment: Can you add CSS? `.row .row{ width: inherit !important; }`